# "for someone to" verb phrases

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm always curisous about the phrase **"for someone to"** verb which is quite common in English.

However, I noticed sometimes it is not proper.

> **1. She is surprised for me to know her mom.** - *Incorrect*

Correct one is **"You are suprised that I know her mom."**

> **Somehow, she is surprised at me to know her mom**

is this fine??

> **2. A computer is hard for me to deal with.**

I think **"for me to deal with"** is acceptable in the sentence. Is it because the preposition **"for"** is accetable with adjective **"hard"**?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Firstly, and importantly, "for" is not a preposition here but a clause **subordinator**, a special marker for infinitival clauses that contain a subject. The simple answer to your question is that some adjectives license (specifically permit) infinitival clauses as complement while others don't. "Hard" is one that does, but "surprised" is one that doesn't (it licenses declarative content clauses, cf. "She is surprised that I know her mom")

Comment: A sample of those adjectives that do license infinitival subjects are "anxious, difficult easy, essential, foolish, good, hard, important, impossible, necessary, possible, ridiculous, usual".

Comment: Thank you Bill for your comment. Does it mean it depend on?

Comment: There's no easy 'rule' to follow. You just have to become acquainted with those adjectives that can license a _for_ infinitival clause.

Answer (score 1):

There are  predicates that can be complemented by the pattern **for {someone} to {VERB}** in which the predicate does not apply to {someone}.

> They are ready for her to sing.

There, the readiness is *theirs*, not hers.

Why can **ready** be complemented by the pattern but **surprised** cannot be?

Because the preposition **for** in this pattern introduces a *prospect*.

They can be waiting, hoping, ready, eager for her to sing.

A *surprised* state occurs with things that have taken place, not with things that have not yet taken place, not with prospective things. Something that has happened surprises us. We cannot be surprised by something which has not yet happened.

So, you must examine the predicate

> She is surprised
>
> It is easy
>
> They are eager

and assess whether it is one that can be complemented by a prospect.

You might be thinking, "That is easy for you to say, but hard for me to understand. What is a prospect?"

A *prospect* is something awaited or envisioned or contemplated, a possibility  not yet an actuality.